Create dynamic object type from two arrays/tuples of keys and values
I have an array of keys and a tuple of values types.
const keys = ["name", "age", "isAlive"] as const;
type Values = [string, number, boolean];

How can I use them to dynamically construct the following type?
type DesiredType = {
   name: string;
   age: number;
   isAlive: boolean;
}

I have tried:
const keys = ["name", "age", "isAlive"] as const;
type Values = [string, number, boolean];

type ObjFromArrays<K extends readonly string[], V extends any[]> = {
  [I in K[number]]: V[number];
};

type DesiredType = ObjFromArrays<typeof keys, Values>;

But it doesn't work because it iterates on K but not on V.

(see prev comment) I'm guessing you're looking for code like in this playground link. If so, please [edit] to fix your example (or I'll do it if you want) and then I'll write an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Sorry for the typos. I've fixed them. And yes. Your answer is absolutely on point. Wow, that is quite an esoteric type signature!

I just fixed a new typo. Is there a reason you're using K for an array of values? The K type parameter name is usually used for keylike types; it's not "the next thing after T". I'd expect you to have something like K for the key array and V for the value array. Do you mind if I [edit] the question to use those names so it's more conventional?

Yes, if you have the power to edit my question to make it more didactic, please go ahead. And thanks again for the very detailed answer.

Essentially you want ObjFromArrays<K, V> to take two data types of the same shape, where the first one K holds keys, and the second one V holds values, and you want to join them into a single object type where each key is paired with each value. The way to do this is by writing a mapped type over the relevant indices I of the K data type, and using key remapping to use K[I] as the key, and V[I] as the value.  Assuming K is a tuple type, then the relevant indices are the numeric-like string keys of K corresponding to positions in the tuple. That is, if K looks like ["name", "age", "isAlive"], then the indices we want to iterate over is "0" | "1" | "2".
Here's how we implement that:
type ObjFromArrays<
  K extends readonly string[], 
  V extends Record<keyof K, any>
> = {
    [I in `${number}` & keyof K as K[I]]: V[I];
};

Here K has been constrained to a (readonly) array of strings, while V has been constrained to have the same indices as K. You could write V extends readonly string[] also, but then you'd need to check inside your implementation that each index I of K was also a valid index of V, and do something if not.  We want to prevent ["name", "age", "isAlive"] for K and something like [string] for V, where the indices don't match. Instead, by constraining to Record<keyof K, any> we're basically requiring that V have at least the same indices as K.
The mapped type iterates over the keys of K (keyof K) which are also (&) numeric-like strings. (`${number}`). The reason why I intersect with `${number}` is to avoid iterating over all the apparent keys of arraylike types, such as "length" and "reduce" and "forEach", etc.  For each such key I, the key of the output type is K[I] and the value is V[I].
Let's test it out:
const keys = ["name", "age", "isAlive"] as const;
type Values = [string, number, boolean];
type DesiredType = ObjFromArrays<typeof keys, Values>;
/* type DesiredType = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    isAlive: boolean;
} */

Looks good.
Playground link to code
